# Angular2 form reset with submitted values

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How can we reset an Angular2 form with submitted data, when I use `this.form.reset()`, the form get updated with the initial values, I want to reset it with the submitted values, to give the user a chance to modify some inputs without retyping all the values.

I'm using Angular `2.2.0`.

Comment: Then why are you resetting it?

Comment: the app create some graphs based on the values submitted by the user, I want the user to be able to modify some values to regenerate the graph if he sees that the graph is not correct without retyping all the values.

Comment: I get that but the answer is just don't reset the form, leave the model that you submitted in tact (I hope you are using model binding like you should).

Comment: when I try to submit the form again, the whole page get reloaded.

Comment: Thats probably because you have `<button type="submit"` instead of `<button type="button"` OR you are not calling `$event.preventDefault()`. With angular 2 you should not have any post backs, if you do you have bad html and need to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in the logic of the `onSubmit` function defined in the component.